# Do not append the div if it was appended before

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pretty simple - if I click on a `<li>` tag, I want it to be displayed below the `<ul>`. If it has been added before, I don't want to add it again.

This is what I have tried:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.plugin-list li', function() {
    let chosenSlug = $(this).attr('data-plugin-slug');
    var doNotAddThisPlugin = false;
    if ($('.plugin_tag').length === 0) {       
        $('.plugin-list').after(`<div class="plugin_tag tag" data-chosen-plugin-value="${$(this).attr('data-plugin-value')}" data-chosen-plugin-slug="${$(this).attr('data-plugin-slug')}">${$(this).attr('data-plugin-value')}</div>`);
    }
    else {
        $('.plugin_tag').each(function(i, o) {            
            if (chosenSlug === $(this).attr('data-chosen-plugin-slug')) {
                var doNotAddThisPlugin = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        console.log(doNotAddThisPlugin); // Always false
        if (doNotAddThisPlugin === false) {            
            $('.plugin-list').after(`<div class="plugin_tag tag" data-chosen-plugin-value="${$(this).attr('data-plugin-value')}" data-chosen-plugin-slug="${$(this).attr('data-plugin-slug')}">${$(this).attr('data-plugin-value')}</div>`);
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="plugin-list">
  <li class="plugin-chosen" data-plugin-value="Hello Dolly" data-plugin-slug="hello-dolly">Hello Dolly</li>
  <li class="plugin-chosen" data-plugin-value="Hello Bar" data-plugin-slug="hellobar">Hello Bar</li>
</ul>
```

So in the case, I don't want "Hello Dolly" or "Hello Bar" to be displayed twice.

If the variable `doNotAddThisPlugin` is set to `true`, I try to break the loop with `return false`. The problem is `doNotAddThisPlugin` is **always** `false`.

What am I doing wrong? If you have a better solution, please feel free to recommend it.

Comment: You are declaring doNotAddThisPlugin with var on line 3, and then on line 10.  Remove var on line 10.

Comment: @JarekKulikowski omg as simple as that! Thank you! i didn't recognize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, the issue is that you are declaring `doNotAddThisPlugin` locally inside the `$().each()` while you are trying to use it as a global variable, that's why its never changed

Just change

```
if (chosenSlug === $(this).attr('data-chosen-plugin-slug')) {
    var doNotAddThisPlugin = true;
    return false;
}
```

For

```
if (chosenSlug === $(this).attr('data-chosen-plugin-slug')) {
    /* no var*/doNotAddThisPlugin = true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet. 
You even don't need that variable doNotAddThisPlugin .

Just check condition for `$('[data-chosen-plugin-slug="'+chosenSlug+'"]').length < 1`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.plugin-list li', function() {
    let chosenSlug = $(this).attr('data-plugin-slug');
    if ($('.plugin_tag').length === 0) {       
        $('.plugin-list').after(`<div class="plugin_tag tag" data-chosen-plugin-value="${$(this).attr('data-plugin-value')}" data-chosen-plugin-slug="${$(this).attr('data-plugin-slug')}">${$(this).attr('data-plugin-value')}</div>`);
    }
    else {
        if($('[data-chosen-plugin-slug="'+chosenSlug+'"]').length < 1) {            
            $('.plugin-list').after(`<div class="plugin_tag tag" data-chosen-plugin-value="${$(this).attr('data-plugin-value')}" data-chosen-plugin-slug="${$(this).attr('data-plugin-slug')}">${$(this).attr('data-plugin-value')}</div>`);
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="plugin-list">
  <li class="plugin-chosen" data-plugin-value="Hello Dolly" data-plugin-slug="hello-dolly">Hello Dolly</li>
  <li class="plugin-chosen" data-plugin-value="Hello Bar" data-plugin-slug="hellobar">Hello Bar</li>
</ul>
```